# suitable replacement for python expression

Tags: python

I want to replace the next expression with something simpler but i'm not sure what my changes impli?

```
if not (self.permission_index_link == 0) \
                                    or not (self.permission_index_link == 8):
```

with

```
if not self.permission_index_link == (0,8):
```

Comment: Notice that your suggestion doesn't work because it compares `permission_index_link` to the *tuple* `(0,8)`, instead of to each of its values in turn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if self.permission_index_link not in (0,8):
    # code
```

Is this what you are looking for? code will run if `self.permission_index_link` is not 0 or 8.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure your initial expression is correct? It will always be true. Didn't you mean to use `and` rather than `or`?

Use the `not in` operator:

```
if self.permission_index_link not in (0,8):
```

Comment: but if i use it this way will it compare to all the numbers in range of 0 to 8, or just with 0 and 8?

Comment: It will only compare to 0, and 8. If you wanted to compare it to the range 0-8, you'd use `... not in range(0, 8)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if self.permission_index.link not in (0,8):
```